# Replace bootstrap column class using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to replace a bootstrap column on a div.
I'm using the following regex for it.

`string.replace("\bcol-\w+-\d+","col-sm-3")`

I tried confirming the regex match [here](http://scriptular.com/). It looks fine. But the string is not getting replaces. Here is a sample snippet. What am i doing wrong?

```js
var string = "col-sm-12 webpage-element-drop ui-sortable ui-droppable selected";

var res = string.replace("\bcol-\w+-\d+","col-sm-3");
alert(res);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've passed it a *string*, not a regular expression, as the first argument. Make it a regular expression instead:

```js
var string = "col-sm-12 webpage-element-drop ui-sortable ui-droppable selected";

var res = string.replace(/\bcol-\w+-\d+/,"col-sm-3");
console.log(res);
```

(I don't think you do, but if you wanted it to replace all matches, add the `g` flag at the end: `/\bcol-\w+-\d+/g`)

**But**, be warned, `\b` will treat `-` like a word boundary. So (for instance) `foo-col-bar-12` would also be changed to `foo-col-sm-3`. It's more complicated if you just want to do ones delimited by spaces *(see also [RomanPerekhrest's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41908092/157247) for another — better, in my view — way to handle those boundaries)*:

```js
var string = "foo-col-sm-12 col-sm-12 webpage-element-drop ui-sortable ui-droppable selected";

var res = string.split(/\s+/).map(function(entry) {
  return entry.replace(/^col-\w+-\d+$/,"col-sm-3");
}).join(" ");
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @T.J. Crowder's answer, to make a replacement more accurate:

```js
var str = "foo-col-sm-12 col-sm-12 webpage-element-drop ui-sortable ui-droppable selected";

var res = str.replace(/(^|\s+)col-\w+-\d+(\s+|$)/, "$1col-sm-3$2");
console.log(res);
```

The capture group `(^|\s+)` at the beginning matches either the beginning of the string or whitespace, and is inserted where the `$1` placeholder is in the replacement string. Similarly, `(\s+|$)` at the end matches whitespace or the end of the string, and is inserted in the replacement where the `$2` is.

Comment: *That's* what was nagging at me earlier when I was answering. Nice one. I took the liberty of updating the answer to handle the boundary at the end, too, and add a bit more explanation.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, thanks for the edit. (your SO "reputation score" is incredible)